# not showing the server address while using python manage.py runserver in django

Tags: python, django, manage.py

while running `python manage.py runserver` , getting this error as given below. using pycharm

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py",
 line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\d
jango.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", li
ne 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templ
atetags\admin_static.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango30Warning
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning' from 'django.utils.deprecation' (C:
\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, i
n _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, i
n run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py
", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\com
mands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\bas
e.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registr
y.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\check
s.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py",
 line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py",
 line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py",
 line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\d
jango.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\d
jango.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\d
jango.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\d
jango.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportErro
r raised when trying to load 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static': cannot import n
ame 'RemovedInDjango30Warning' from 'django.utils.deprecation' (C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\
PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by django versions. You probably upgraded it or something
There is a conflicts in Django versions as you can see in your error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'

So you can try to create a virtual environment and first uninstall and then re install

```
pip uninstall django
```

and then install another version lower then 3.0

```
pip install django==2.2
```

Comment: Thank you.. it worked. what if I want to use django 3.0? what changes I have to do?

Comment: Comment out this line from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango30Warning  in the files admin_static.py and staticfiles.py under template tags folder